# local variable 'post' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Im trying to assign the current logged in username to the existing model through a form. But facing a problem while saving the form

```
#views.py
def create(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form=NotForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post.user = request.user.get_username()
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return redirect('base')
else:
    form=NotForm()
return render(request, 'create.html',{'form':form})

forms.py
class NotForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Note
    fields = ('title', 'desc',)


models.py

class Note(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    user=models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Comment: you can't use `post.user` before the `post` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form=NotForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user.get_username()
        post.save()
        return redirect('base')
```

try this in the view